# How to properly throw exceptions

Tags: java, exception

I am trying to read in data from a binary file into a 2D array while sorting out any negative numbers or values above the max data point (in the int[]).  I can get the array to populate correctly without the exceptions, but is is a requirement to throw exceptions for data outside the acceptable range.  When I add the exceptions the array never populates past the first row.  Any insight would greatly appreciated.

```
public class DataExceedsMaxDataPoint extends Exception {
    public DataExceedsMaxDataPoint() {
        super("Error: Data Exceeds Maximum Data Point");
    }

    public DataExceedsMaxDataPoint(int number, int maxData) {
        super("Error: Data(" + number + ") Exceeds Maximum Data Point(" +
                maxData + ")");
    }
}

public class NegativeData extends Exception {
    public NegativeData() {
        super("Error: NegativeData Not Allowed");
    }

    public NegativeData(int number) {
        super("Error: Negative Data(" + number + ") Not Allowed");
    }
}

import java.io.*;

public class ChemExpDataValidation2 {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
        int[] dataMax = {35, 55, 72, 75, 45, 100}; //max data points
        int[][] chemData = new int[6][10];
        int number;
        int maxData;
        boolean endOfFile = false;

        FileInputStream fstream = new FileInputStream("data.dat");
        DataInputStream inputFile = new DataInputStream(fstream);

        System.out.println("Reading numbers from the file:");

        while (!endOfFile) {
            try {
                for (int row = 0; row < 6; row++) {
                    maxData = dataMax[row];
                    for (int col = 0; col < 10; col++) {
                        number = inputFile.readInt();
                        if (number <= maxData && number > 0) {
                            chemData[row][col] = number;
                        }
                        if (number > maxData) {
                            throw new DataExceedsMaxDataPoint(number, maxData);
                        }
                        if (number < 0) {
                            throw new NegativeData(number);
                        }
                    }
                }
                for (int row = 0; row < 6; row++) {
                    for (int col = 0; col < 10; col++) {
                        System.out.printf("%4d", chemData[row][col]);
                    }
                    System.out.printf("\n");
                }
            } catch (DataExceedsMaxDataPoint e) {
                System.out.println(e.getMessage());
                continue;
            } catch (NegativeData e) {
                System.out.println(e.getMessage());
                continue;
            } catch (EOFException e) {
                endOfFile = true;
            }

        }
        inputFile.close();
        System.out.println("\nDone.");
    }
}
```

Comment: Sorry, but your code's indentation looks like a dogs breakfast.   If you can't be bothered to indent it properly, I can't be bothered to read it.  (Reference: http://www.urbandictionary.com/define.php?term=dog%27s%20breakfast)

Answer (score 1):

Your requirement doesn't make sense.  An exception basically nullifies whatever the try block was doing.  If properly constructed and matched with suitable actions in the catch block, the operation ideally should exactly restore the conditions that existed prior to entering the try.

Comment: Not sure if this is an answer. On the other hand, I'm not even sure if OP asked a question

Answer (score 1):

try/catch blocks are pretty confusing at first at least it was for me. But how I like to look at them is a try this and if it doesn't work DO NOT crash the program but limp to the finish line (or try again with new variables and see if that works).

```
try{
    someMethod(); // some method that could result in a crash of the program but want to try it
                 //if it works great but if not here is why but didn't blow up 
    Object = someOtherObject; // for example could be null, and throw an error but you want to try it first
}catch(Exception e){
    displayMessage(); // inform the user that the process couldn't go through 
                      //could also send yourself a copy of the stack trace 
}
```

The program will continue since it "tried" to do it but just didn't work but was able to go back.

When you say you can get it to populate without the exception that is good which means your logic is working well. I would just put it all in 1 try/catch and if it fails it will catch it. Keep it simple :)

Hope this helps or points you in the right direction.

Answer (score 0):

If invalid records qualify really as exceptional, then throw an exception, and there is no other "result". This effectively means that there is no way to recover from it, and it makes no sense to continue with this task (that's the way Scala recommends to use exceptions).

If invalid records are just to be ignored, then there is no need for exceptions.
And if like to return a list of invalid records as well, put the successful records and the list of invalid records together in a class, and return this one.

Generally speaking, while importing data (especially from plain files), I normally do not use any exceptions at all, because it's so common that there are validation problems. So that's not really exceptional, and users are happy if you present a *complete* list of invalid records instead of just one exception thrown right after the first error.

So sometimes the answer to "how to properly throw an exception" is just "not to throw any at all".

Answer (score 0):

For starters, your throws don't make much sense. You should be throwing an exception when exceptional behavior occurs, and the calling method should be responsible for handling it.  Here, you're both expecting the error and catching it in the same method block, which doesn't flow the same way.

To put it simply, [exceptions break the natural flow of the program.](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/exceptions/definition.html)  If a `Throwable` occurs in any block, the execution of that particular block is halted, and only the `catch`/`finally` conditions are handled.  Your issue - that data doesn't populate itself past the first row - is affected by this; something that is considered "exceptional" causes the continued looping to halt.

You've got a couple of options:

- **Don't fight the exceptions.**  They're working as intended - if some exceptional state occurred while entering, what you're saying is that you don't want the code to continue past that point.  In layman's terms, pass valid data.
- **Don't use exceptions.** If you want to disregard invalid data, then there's no real reason to have them in the first place.
- **Pigeonhole the exceptions to the narrowest scope possible.**  You could place the `try...catch` block just after you read the int.  Better yet, write it as a separate method that declares its checked throws, and call it:

  ```
  public static int checkValidInput(int number, int maxData)
          throws DataExceedsMaxDataPoint, NegativeData {
      if (number > maxData) {
          throw new DataExceedsMaxDataPoint(number, maxData);
      } else if (number < 0) {
          throw new NegativeData(number);
      } else {
           return number;
      }
  }
  ```

  ---

  ```
  for (int row = 0; row < 6; row++) {
      maxData = dataMax[row];
      for (int col = 0; col < 10; col++) {
          try {
              number = checkValidInput(inputFile.readInt(), maxData);
          } catch (DataExceedsMaxDataPoint e) {
              System.out.println(e.getMessage());
          } catch (NegativeData e) {
              System.out.println(e.getMessage());
          } catch (IOException e) { // generify the EOFException instead
              endOfFile = true;
          } 
      }
  }
  ```